# Numerical Search

Tags: 2010, search

This is possibly a silly amateur question however it has me completely stumped, and I'd really appreciate any input at this moment in time.

Our organisation use large amounts of excel and word documents, most of which contain a Reference/number pattern (E.G Ref:13555).  I've uploaded a number of test documents and fully crawled the document library, however when I come to search for the reference number - nothing is returned.  On the other hand when specific text is searched it returns a result.

Essentially can the search function look up specific numerical values in a document?

Is there something I've overlooked here, or am I going about searching the entirely wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: If you're actually typing REF:13555 in the search box, it'll look for a metadata property called REF with the value of 13555. Have you tried enclosing in quotes such as "REF:13555"?